# Adding background color to app.js on react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to add a default color for all my screens on react-native. My entry file doesn't have a default react-native component that takes in styles as prop. Hence, I'll be asking "*How to add styles when Navigation container is present"*. I have tried adding the *cardStyle prop on* `Drawer.Screen`  but it doesn't work.

Here's a sample of my code

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name='SignUp' component={SignUp} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Reset Password' component={ResetPassword}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Verify Email" component={EmailVerification} />          
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "default color", background-color or header-color?

Comment: backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

Simply we have to create a Root Component in which we can put the background color.

For Example.

Create a Root Component with background color:

```
const RootComponent = props => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR" }} >
            {props.children}
        </View>
    )
}

export default RootComponent;
```

Now we can import the Root Component in our screens in which screens we are supposed to show the same background color.

for Example:

```
const HomeScreen = props => {
    return (
         <RootComponent>
         {
             /* YOUR HOME SCREEN COMPONENTS... */  
         }
         </RootComponent>
    )
}
```